# MongoParseError: Ports not accepted with 'mongodb+srv' URIs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongo

столкнулся с данной ошибкой при запуске mongo в docker **MongoParseError: Ports not accepted with 'mongodb+srv' URIs**.
Очень много гуглил и не нашёл ничего кроме того как попробовать процентное кодирование, оно тоже не помогло.
Моё подключение выглядит следующим образом **'mongodb+srv://user:pa!sSw%oRd@11.11.111.11:11111/test**.
Подскажите что могу ещё попробовать

Comment: А вот `+srv` у вас там осознанно прописано? Тогда номера портов должен отдавать ваш DNS server, из соответствующей SRV-записи, о чем монга и пытается вам сказать.

Comment: Если без +srv то выходит такая же ошибка **MongoParseError: Ports not accepted with 'mongodb+srv' URIs**